# Neater way of prying a DECLARE from a &body

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a macro that generates a `DEFUN` call—accordingly, I want to ensure that any `DECLARE`s in the body to the macro get placed immediately after the `DEFUN`. Here's what I have:

```
(defmacro defsynced (name (&rest args) &body body)
  (let* ((decl (if (eql (caar body) 'cl:declare)
                   (list (car body))))
         (body (if decl
                   (cdr body)
                   body)))
    `(defun ,name ,args
       ,@decl
       (bordeaux-threads:with-lock-held (*request-lock*)
         ,@body))))
```

Unfortunately it's rather ugly and not necessarily obvious what's happening here. Is there a nicer way you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since declaration parsing can be tricky, there is a library called [parse-declarations](http://common-lisp.net/project/parse-declarations/) that helps with it.  It's available from [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org/).

```
(ql:quickload "parse-declarations-1.0")
```

The [`parse-body`](http://common-lisp.net/project/parse-declarations/manual/html_node/parse_002dbody.html#parse_002dbody) function is particularly relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the ticket! This has provoked another question which I'll post separately.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not complete because there can be one *or more* declarations.

Though you can use some off the shelf function for this, it makes for a good study of a technique that can be useful in similar situations.

If you have a list of the form

```
(alpha beta x epsilon ... omega)
```

where x is an item of interest on which you want to split the list, you can use the `member` function to find the sublist which starts with `x` and then the `ldiff` function to fetch the prefix of that list `(alpha beta)` which excludes `(x epsilon omega)`. First step:

```
(member-if-not (lambda (x) (eq x 'declare)) '(declare declare 3 4 5))

-> (3 4 5)
```

Of course, we are looking for `(declare ...)` not `declare`. We can't use `:key #'car` for this because forms might not be conses, so:

```
(member-if-not (lambda (x) (and (consp x) (eq (car x) 'declare)))
               '((declare foo) (declare bar) 3 4 5))
-> (3 4 5)
```

Now how to get the declarations and the remaining forms by themselves:

```
(defun separate-decls-and-body (body)
  (let* ((just-the-code (member-if-not (lambda (x)
                                         (and (consp x) (eq (car x) 'declare)))
                                        body))
         (just-the-decls (ldiff body just-the-code)))
    (values just-the-decls just-the-code)))
```

Tests:

```
> (separate-decls-and-body '((declare (optimize (speed 3))) (declare (type)) 1 2 3))
((DECLARE (OPTIMIZE (SPEED 3))) (DECLARE (TYPE))) ;
(1 2 3)

> (separate-decls-and-body '((declare (optimize (speed 3)))))
((DECLARE (OPTIMIZE (SPEED 3)))) ;
NIL

> (separate-decls-and-body '())
NIL ;
NIL

> (separate-decls-and-body '(1 2 3))
NIL ;
(1 2 3)
```

The `member` family and `ldiff` are your friends. `ldiff` is based on the fact that `member` returns a substructure of the original list and not a copy; it just marches down the list looking for that pointer, and returns all prior items as a new list.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extensive comment! I probably need to brush up more on my sequence/list operations; using `MEMBER` to get a sublist like that is very neat.

Answer (score 1):

No answer is complete without the ritualistic sacrifice to the `loop` deity:

```
(defun separate-decls-and-body (body)
  (loop for sub-body on body
        for form = (first sub-body) 
        until (or (atom form) (not (eq (first form) 'declare)))
        collecting form into decls
        finally (return (values decls sub-body))))
```